# Is there any guideline to help clojure programmer to determine in what situation should be built in macros over function?

Tags: clojure, macros

When I was reading a book "On Lisp", I find that there is an interesting topic about macros (chapter 7 in the book), convert the example to Clojure and execute in REPL (Clojure). Both of them are almost identical, I still don't know when the price of coding should be built in macros when I can build that as a function. Is there any guideline to help programmer to determine in what situation should be built in macros over function?

**Example in Macros**

```
(defmacro nif [expr pos zero neg]
  `(case (Integer/signum ~expr)
     1 ~pos
     0 ~zero
     -1 ~neg))

(map #(nif % 'p 'z 'n) [0 2.5 -8])
=> (z p n)
```

**Example in function**

```
(defn nif2 [expr pos zero neg]
  (case (Integer/signum expr)
    1  pos
    0 zero
    -1 neg))

(map #(nif2 % 'p 'z 'n) [0 2.5 -8])
=> (z p n)
```

Comment: I found [*Mastering Clojure Macros*](https://pragprog.com/titles/cjclojure/mastering-clojure-macros/) useful.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that the new symbol `nif` ***is a language extension***. The implementation of `nif` ***is a compiler extension*** which adds a layer of pre-processing of the source code AST before normal compilation resumes.

This is only useful if you cannot already do something in Clojure with either a built-in or user-defined function. For example, the macro `clojure.core/when` is a simplified version of `clojure.core/if` (see [the source code](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.10.1/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L493)), and is not possible to write as a function.

Also, note that functions can do things that macros cannot; i.e. you can compose functions, but you cannot compose macros.

I haven't seen that book, but for this example there is zero benefit to writing the macro.  It is just an academic exercise to prove you could do it.

However, note that you cannot use `map` with a macro, only a function. The example only works at all because you wrap the macro with a function:

```
#(nif % 'p 'z 'n)
```

which is the same as the anonymous function

```
(fn [val] 
  (nif val 'p 'z 'n))
```

Normally, you'd just write it as

```
(defn val->sign
  [val]
  (case (Integer/signum val)
    1  :p
    0  :z
   -1  :n))
```

and invoke it as

```
(mapv val->sign [0 2.5 -8])
;=>  [:z :p :n]
```

This example also has zero benefit to allowing custom symbols are the return values. It is more natural in Clojure to just use pre-defined keywords for the return value, as shown above.

Comment: I think macros do compose, but at the level they operate, at the AST level, ie. I can use my macro within the scope of your macro and it works, provided it is done correctly. I can write a macro that takes names of macro of single argument and expand into a chain of macros `(with-decorators [a b c] ...)` becomes `(a (b (c ...)))` (if that makes sense in your program); I agree they do not compose at runtime

Comment: The point of the macro is to extract out the control flow. With your version, `val->sign` extracts out a `case` expression for you, but then to do anything interesting with the result...you have to write another `case` expression to switch on the sign! `(nif x (fetch-positive-result) (println "Error, zero not allowed") (fetch-negative-result))` is much easier to write with `nif` than it would be using `val->sign`. It could be argued this is less readable: the +/0/- are hidden - but it's a reasonable tradeoff to make, and requires a macro.

Comment: I assumed this problem was just a "mental exercise", and probably not a very useful one at that IMHO. Since it seems unrealistic, I don't even pretend to guess at how it might be used.